# Best way to set up SSI with SAML and Azure AD

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

Based on this article, I am under the impression you can use the SAML standard to authenticate users on your web application using Azure AD:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol

However it is not entire clear on all of the small steps required to do this. So I had a go and did the following to figure out for myself the first step which is to get the URL that the Service Provider needs to redirect the browser to authenticate using the IdP (i.e. Azure AD):

- I set up a separate AD in Azure, on the free tier.
- Within that AD I created an Application.
- There was no option in the Application to set up SSI

I then use the following code to generate a URL for the SAML browser request:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

namespace AzureSAMLExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        // Call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml returns the SingleSignOnService element below:

        public const string SingleSignOnServiceUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/saml2";
        public const string SingleSignOnQueryString = "?SAMLRequest={0}";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol
            var SAMLRequestXML = $@"<samlp:AuthnRequest
xmlns=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion""
ID=""id6c1c178c166d486687be4aaf5e482730""
Version=""2.0"" IssueInstant=""{DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")}""
xmlns:samlp=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"">
<Issuer xmlns=""urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"">ISSUER</Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>";

            var url = $"{SingleSignOnServiceUrl}?SAMLRequest={DeflateEncode(SAMLRequestXML)}";
        }

        private static string DeflateEncode(string val)
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true), new UTF8Encoding(false)))
            {
                writer.Write(val);
                writer.Close();

                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And put the resultant URL in the browser.

I tried a few different values for the ISSUER including

- http://localhost
- Our company domain name
- https://sts.windows.net/{tennant guid}
- {tennant guid}
- {application guid}

But none of that worked.

As you can see I am using the common URL not the tenant-specific. I am not sure which one is best to use.

In every case I got the following response when visiting the url:

[image]

So any directions on what I have done wrong?

- Do I need a premium level AD or is free OK?
- Should I use a tenant or common end point?
- Is there something wrong with the XML or the encoding I have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD provides the active directory service for free. To connect to the active directory via SAML protocol, you need to switch to a paid plan. Once you are on a paid plan and configured the SAML setup, Azure will be acting like a SAML IdP (identity provider). At this point, I would recommend testing the Authentication flow using an external IAM service configured as SAML SP (Service Provider) instead of crafting a solution on your own. E.g., you may try [Auth0 as SAML SP](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-sp-generic) for this purpose.

Architecture would be something like this with the above setup;

`Your App <= OAuth => Auth0 <= SAML => Azure AD`

If you don't want to pay Azure for the SAML support, you could federate users to Azure AD with the WsFed protocol. This is also [supported with Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory/v2).

`Your App <= OAuth => Auth0 <= WsFed => Azure AD`

[This link](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43) might be useful with some links for **.Net** if you need to support SAML protocol within your App and also provides some more links to have a broader view of possibilities.

Disclaimer: I work for Auth0.

Comment: If the application is listed on the Azure gallery would that allow free AD users to integrate. It seems to say that here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Azure so please take this with a grain of salt; From the link it appears that you can integrate your AD users for up to 10 apps available in the Azure gallery. But for adding a custom app as SAML SP, you need to have a Premium P1 subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need Azure AD Premium.

Here's an [example](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-azure-ad-and-the-sustainsys-saml-v2-0-for-net-core-stack-5421398d00e4) using a custom SAML connection.

Then Azure AD / Enterprise applications / SSO.